# MySQL - how to find difference date between each row

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi Programming Master,

I need help with this. This is an employee data, the `NULL` in `TerminationDate` refer to current date, it's mean that the employee are still working.
I need to find longest time (in days) where there is no one hired or terminated.

Table Name : `Employee`
Column Name : `ID`, `HireDate`, `TerminationDate`

```
Employee

ID  HireDate    TerminationDate
1   2009-06-20  2016-01-01
2   2010-02-12  NULL
3   2012-03-14  NULL
4   2013-09-10  2014-01-01
5   2013-09-10  NULL
6   2015-04-10  2015-05-01
7   2010-04-11  2016-01-01
8   2012-05-12  NULL
9   2011-04-13  2015-02-13
```

I have developed process of what need to do

1. Combine data in `HireDate` and `TerminationDate` (it should have 18 rows)
2. Order the date
3. Find the difference between each date from Row(n) and Row(n-1)
4. Get the max difference

However I don't know how to do it in MySQL or if it is even possible. I wonder if there is any other method? Please help me

Answer (score 0):

This is rather complicated in MySQL, prior to version 8.  But you can do:

```
select dte, next_dte, 
       datediff(coalesce(next_dte, curdate()), dte) as diff
from (select dte,
             (select min(d2.dte)
              from ((select hiredate as dte
                     from t
                    ) union   -- intentionally remove duplicates
                    (select terminationdate as dte
                     from t
                     where teminationdate is not null
                    )
                   ) d2
              where d2.dte > d.dte
             ) next_dte
      from ((select hiredate as dte
             from t
            ) union   -- intentionally remove duplicates
            (select terminationdate as dte
             from t
             where teminationdate is not null
            )
           ) d
     ) d
order by diff desc
limit 1;
```

Note that this finds the the most recent period, based on the current date.  You can adjust this by replacing `curdate()` with whatever cutoff date you have in mind.  If you don't want the most recent period, add `where next_dte is not null` to the outer query.